# If statements SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

I wanted to calculate the median I don't know what is wrong here
UPDATE:

```
def median(a,b,c):
    if a>b:
        if b>c:
        return b
        else:
        if a>c:
            return c
        else:
            return a
    else:
        if b<c:
            return b
        else:
        if a>c:
            return a
        else: 
            return c
```

My error is :   File "prog.py", line 4
    return b
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Your indentation is very poor. You should make it consistent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong. Each `else:` must line up with its corresponding `if ...:`, and each nested block must be indented.

For example,

```
        if a>c:
            return c
                else:
                    return a
```

should read

```
        if a>c:
            return c
        else:
            return a
```

Code that isn't indented correctly isn't valid Python.

P.S. The entire function can be rewritten as follows:

```
def median(a, b, c):
    return sorted((a, b, c))[1]
```

Comment: Thanks you mean spaces are important? and each else should be beneath it's if?

Comment: @NeginNicki: The first `return b` is not indented correctly. Neither are the `if a>c:` blocks (BTW, you can replace these with `elif` to reduce the amount of indentation). I'd recommend reading a Python tutorial; this will probably be covered on page one, and will save you lots of time.

Comment: Thank you so much I used my nested one completely ok now:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to un-indent the else statement on line 5.  Whitespace matters in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Your `else` needs to have the same indentation as the `if`.  That's how python knows where blocks start and end.

Answer (score 0):

The `else:` on line 5 is not indented to match its `if:` on line 3. Python is a whitespace-sensitive language.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
def median(a,b,c):
  lst = [a, b, c]
  lst.sort()
  return lst[1]
```

might be less efficient but a little easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see how "return b" is indented less than "return c"? Fix that and it should work.